Django request process data saving
I have django asgi app. And I want to have POST /routes handling, that would be something like:
async def routes(request):   
    if is_first_request_from_user(request):
        generator = RouteGenerator()
        save_generator_for_user(request, generator)
        return await generator.first_generate()
    else:
        generator = get_generator_for_user(request)
        return await generator.further_generate()

And RouteGenerator object has state and stores some complex data like heap, maps, sets etc. and it is attached to each user and should be stored in local memory. So how to implement it in django? Should I use some kind of django cache?
I'm not really good at python, especially django, and for me the most straightforward solution would be to store some global map {request_id: route_generator}, however while googling nowhere was mentioned such a simple approach

In django tutorial it's said that default cache is per process, that means that it will not work as expected if user requests processed in different processes
